# local commands don't get executed after remote command via python fabric

Tags: python, fabric

I have a python script that should do some things locally (`local.py`) and, at some point, it should start a script on a remote server (`remote.sh`). It takes quite some time for `remote.sh` to finish, up to 12h. Upon completion of `remote.sh`, `local.py` should still do a few things, like printing messages into log files. An example of the aforementioned tasks can be found below:

```
import fabric

# fabric connection parameters
cHL = fabric.Connection(host='user@hostname', 
                            connect_kwargs={'password':'pwd'})

# do some stuff locally

# do some stuff on the remote server e.g. creating a file with multiple entries
for i in 'a b c d'.split():
    cHL.run(f"echo '{i}' >> /path/to/remoteFile.txt")

# do again some local stuff - they all work

# here is where I launch remote.sh. after which the commands to do anything locally fail
remoteCommand = f"remote.sh -p1 {param1} -p2 {param2}"
cHL.run(commandHLupload) # this script does finish

# commands to do things locally e.g. append messages to log files don't work anymore
```

I initially thought that this could be a matter that I was not not explicitly closing my connection after calling `remote.sh`. I put then the command within a context manager, as described [here](https://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/connection.html)

```
with cHL:
    cHL.run(remoteCommand)
```

I got the same results though i.e. the commands downstream of `remote.sh` do not get executed.

Also I noticed that `local.py`, which is called automatically by a cron job, keeps running endlessly, that's why I suspected something was wrong with the connection to the remote server in the first place.

Can it be that there is indeed a problem with the connection to the remote server, so that (I) the commands downstream of calling `remote.sh` don't get executed and (II) `local.py` keeps running endlessly? If so, how can I fix that?

Comment: FYI, only tag with [tag:python-3.x] if your question specifically relates to the 3.x version of Python you're using as it differs from other versions. (And always tag with [tag:python] regardless.)